# Understanding Smartctl Output

Tags: smartctl

I'm trying to determine if an old hard drive is failing. It makes a constant, loud, buzzing noise, and has problems shutting down properly.

Smartctl indicates that my hard drive has passed, but also lists numerous errors at the bottom.

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Mobile HDD
Device Model:     ST1000LM035-1RK172
Serial Number:    ZDE1F5CD
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0a3561544
Firmware Version: LVM2
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Dec  2 13:21:54 2022 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 168) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   078   058   034    Pre-fail  Always       -       58414483
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   020    Old_age   Always       -       4039
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   085   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       315028363
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   082   082   000    Old_age   Always       -       15873 (119 200 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   020    Old_age   Always       -       3766
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       153
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   072   049   040    Old_age   Always       -       28 (Min/Max 20/28)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       58
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   032   032   000    Old_age   Always       -       137023
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   028   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       28 (0 6 0 0 0)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x000f   083   083   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       15457 (99 157 0)
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 153 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 153 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 976 hours (40 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 88 4e dd 06  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x06dd4e88 = 115166856

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:25:19.106  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 20 00      00:25:19.090  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:25:09.399  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 20 00      00:25:09.388  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:59.574  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 152 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 976 hours (40 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 88 4e dd 06  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x06dd4e88 = 115166856

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:25:09.399  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 20 00      00:25:09.388  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:59.574  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 20 00      00:24:59.562  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:49.901  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 151 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 976 hours (40 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 88 4e dd 06  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x06dd4e88 = 115166856

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:59.574  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 20 00      00:24:59.562  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:49.901  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 20 00      00:24:49.891  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 18 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:39.968  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 150 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 976 hours (40 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 88 4e dd 06  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x06dd4e88 = 115166856

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:49.901  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 20 00      00:24:49.891  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 18 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:39.968  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 20 00      00:24:39.956  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:30.253  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 149 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 976 hours (40 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 88 4e dd 06  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x06dd4e88 = 115166856

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 18 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:39.968  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 20 00      00:24:39.956  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:30.253  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 20 00      00:24:30.242  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 08 88 4e dd 46 00      00:24:20.410  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: *I'm trying to determine if an old hard drive is failing. It makes a constant, loud, buzzing noise, and has problems shutting down properly.* Not quite sure what needs determining here? Your drive is failing.

Comment: Yup there's a lot to unwrap in that report. There's this that might help https://wiki.unraid.net/Understanding_SMART_Reports

Answer (score -1):

"smartctl -a /dev/sda" will give the information about the particular drive

You can run "smartctl -t short /dev/sda" to perform the SMART short test.

Comment: I would expect the author of whatever answer to have read the question enough to realize that OP did run smartctl.